# Picture doesn't line up with text

Tags: graphics, xetex, formatting, positioning

I've been struggeling for hours with this (simple) problem. After deciding to fresh up my resume I wanted to do it with latex. Problem is, I'm not very experienced with this and now I'm stuck.

I can't seem to place my profile picture where I want it to be. The picture should be placed no higher than "my name" and on the right side.
This is where I am right now:
[image: dfsd]

And here are my files:

> resume.tex

```
\documentclass{resume}

\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for figures
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{changepage}

\name{My name}
\jobtitle{Student}
\born{xx.xx.xxxx}
\address{Some street, some city}
\phone{0123456789}
\email{mail@mail.com}

\newcommand{\userinformation}[1]{\renewcommand{\userinformation}{#1}} %

\userinformation{

\begin{figure}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth,right]{photo.jpg} % Your photo
\end{figure}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustwidth}{}{-8cm}
    \userinformation
\end{adjustwidth}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{rSection}{Utdanning}

{\bf  Some university} \hfill {Year - Year} \\
University
\item Some text

\end{rSection}
\end{document}
```

> resume.cls

```
\ProvidesClass{resume}[2010/09/17 v0.1 Resume class]

\LoadClass[11pt,letterpaper]{article} % Font size and paper type

\usepackage[left=0.5in,top=0.3in,right=0.5in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Remove paragraph indentation
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % Colorize    
\usepackage{hyperref} % Clickable links
\usepackage{xhfill} % Customizable hrulefill
\usepackage{array} % Required for boldface (\bf and \bfseries) tabular columns
\usepackage{ifthen} % Required for ifthenelse statements
\usepackage{fontspec}

\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page numbers

\definecolor{accentColor}{RGB}{72,105,24}
\definecolor{titleColor}{RGB}{132,129,129}
\definecolor{textColor}{RGB}{90,91,94}
\definecolor{linkColor}{RGB}{49,117,194}

\hypersetup{
 colorlinks=true,
 urlcolor=linkColor
}

% New command for the blue bullets
\newcommand{\bluebullet}{\textcolor{accentColor}{$\circ$}~~} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\name}[1]{
 \def\@name{#1}
}
\def\@name{} % Sets \@name to empty by default

\newcommand{\jobtitle}[1] {
 \def\@jobtitle{#1} % Defines the \jobtitle command to set name
}

\newcommand{\address}[1]{\def\@address{#1}}
\newcommand{\phone}[1]{\def\@phone{#1}}
\newcommand{\website}[1]{\def\@website{#1}}
\newcommand{\email}[1]{\def\@email{#1}}
\newcommand{\born}[1]{\def\@born{#1}}

% \printname is used to print the name as a page header
\newcommand{\printname} {
 \begingroup
   \Large\bf\textcolor{accentColor}{\@name}\hfil
   \smallskip\break
 \endgroup
}

% \printjobtitle is used to print the name as a page header
\newcommand{\printjobtitle} {
 \begingroup
   \large\bf\textcolor{textColor}{\@jobtitle}\hfil
   \smallskip\break
 \endgroup
}

% \printjobtitle is used to print the name as a page header
\let\contactsize\normalsize
\let\contactskip\smallskip
\newcommand{\printcontact} {
\begin{tabular}{ l l }
    \@ifundefined{@born}{}{\contactsize\textcolor{accentColor}{Født:} & \contactsize\bf\textcolor{textColor}{\@born} \\ \noalign{\contactskip}}

    \@ifundefined{@phone}{}{\contactsize\textcolor{accentColor}{Telefon:} & \contactsize\bf\textcolor{textColor}{\@phone} \\ \noalign{\contactskip}}

    \@ifundefined{@address}{}{\contactsize\textcolor{accentColor}{Adresse:} & \contactsize\bf\textcolor{textColor}{\@address} \\ \noalign{\contactskip}}

    \@ifundefined{@website}{}{\contactsize\textcolor{accentColor}{Website:} & \contactsize\bf\href{\@website}{\@website} \\ \noalign{\contactskip}}

    \@ifundefined{@email}{}{\contactsize\textcolor{accentColor}{Mail:} &    \contactsize\bf\href{mailto:\@email}{\@email}  \\}

 \end{tabular}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PRINT THE HEADING LINES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\let\ori@document=\document
\renewcommand{\document}{
  \ori@document  % Begin document
  \printname % Print the name specified with \name
  \@ifundefined{@jobtitle}{}{\printjobtitle}
 \printcontact
}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ---------
%   SECTION FORMATTING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Defines the rSection environment for the large sections within the CV
\newenvironment{rSection}[1]{ % 1 input argument - section name
  \smallskip
  \textcolor{accentColor}{\rule{1cm}    {.4mm}\quad\hbox{\MakeUppercase{\bf{\textit{#1}}}}\quad\xhrulefill{accentColor} {.4mm}}
 \smallskip
 \begin{list}{}{ % List for each individual item in the section
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em} % Margin within the section
  }
  \item[]
}{
 \end{list}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE FORMATTING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newenvironment{rSubsection}[4]{ % 4 input arguments - company name, year(s) employed, job title and location
 {\bf #1} \hfill {#2} % Bold company name and date on the right
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{ % If the third argument is not specified, don't print the job title and location line
  \\
  {\em #3} \hfill {\em #4} % Italic job title and location
  }\smallskip
  \begin{list}{$\cdot$}{\leftmargin=0em} % \cdot used for bullets, no indentation
   \itemsep -0.5em \vspace{-0.5em} % Compress items in list together for aesthetics
  }{
 \end{list}
 \vspace{0.5em} % Some space after the list of bullet points
}
```

All help is appriciated!

Comment: Why don't you try with a stabdard class such as `moderncv`?

Comment: how does this question differ from [Move picture to align with text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/360703/579) ?

Comment: It's basically the same. Just felt that my last post didn't really shed light on what I wanted to achieve. Sorry if I broke some rules @barbarabeeton

Comment: no "rules broken", but the other question has no answers, and isn't likely to get any, so it will remain a pesky item on the list for the monthly "answer the unanswered".  it's also unlikely to help someone else coming here looking for information.  so if you agree, you can edit anything useful from that question into this one, and delete that one.  that's cleaner than having other people vote on closing it -- you can always modify or delete your own questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed everything that has to do with `\userinformation`. Instead I put the image in the name directly, similar to Steven B. Segletes, but used `\raisebox` instead och `stackengine`.

Changed code:

```
\usepackage{calc}%% New
\name{My name%
  \sbox0{\includegraphics[height=7em]{example-image}}
  \hfill \raisebox{-\ht0+0.7\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\usebox0}% Your photo
}

\jobtitle{Student}
\born{xx.xx.xxxx}
\address{Some street, some city}
\phone{0123456789}
\email{mail@mail.com}

%\newcommand{\userinformation}[1]{\renewcommand{\userinformation}{#1}} %

%\userinformation{%
  % \begin{figure}
  %   \hfill
  % \includegraphics[height=7em,right]{example-image}% Your photo
  % \end{figure}
%}

\begin{document}

%\begin{adjustwidth}{}{-8cm}
%    \userinformation
%\end{adjustwidth}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this one! I liked this code the best because of its simplicity

Answer (score 3):

This certainly could stand additional improvement, but I did a few things.  I got rid of the `adjustbox`, I made `\userinformation` part of the `\name` and limited its height to the same as the student details.  Importantly, the image should not be part of `figure` environment, which is a floating entity.

```
\documentclass{resume}

\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for figures
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\name{My name\hfill \smash{\userinformation}}
\jobtitle{Student}
\born{xx.xx.xxxx}
\address{Some street, some city}
\phone{0123456789}
\email{mail@mail.com}

\newcommand{\userinformation}[1]{\renewcommand{\userinformation}{#1}} %

\userinformation{%
    \belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{%
      \includegraphics[height=6\baselineskip]{example-image}}% Your photo
}

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{rSection}{Utdanning}

{\bf  Some university} \hfill {Year - Year} \\
University
\item Some text

\end{rSection}
\end{document}
```

[image]